# Zooming on a specific path of an SVG with JS

Tags: javascript, svg

So I'm trying to create an interactive map of Europe for a school project.
I downloaded the SVG map and now I'm trying to play with it with js

I'd like to zoom, or scale on a country when double clicking on it, and I don't have any clue on how do to this, I'm new to JS.
So I guess there is a way to scale the svg and centering it on a specific path at the same time.

Thanks

Comment: Start from here: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5189284

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for details on how to ask a good question. In addition you'll want to share the code that you currently have so that others know what you are working with.